# Another Interpretation of Distance?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is as follows:

> Starting at the same spot on a circular track that is 80 meters in diameter, Hillary and Eugene run in opposite directions, at 300 meters per minute and 240 meters per minute, respectively. They run for 50 minutes. What distance separates Hillary and Eugene when they finish? There is more than one way to interpret the word distance in this question.

I know the literal interpretation of distance, which can be figured out by finding the difference between the distance between Hillary and Eugene after the 50 minutes (which is 3,000 meters). But what is the other interpretation of "distance"? Are they asking for displacement (although I know that distance and displacement are not interchangeable)? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They could mean distance on the track or linear distance.

Comment: How would you find linear distance?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you may interpret distance in this text as

- linear distance, that is the length of the straight segment connecting H and E;
- “circular” distance, the distance along the circuit, that is how far would H need to run on the track to reach E if E stopped (or the other way around of course).

Note that in the second case there are two ways to reach a point in the circuit — running clockwise or counterclockwise — therefore there you may even split further the interpretation of “distance”.

Comment: I am not sure how I should be finding the linear distance. Can you please help me on that?

Answer (score 1):

Since they are running in *opposite* directions, their relative speed is $540$ m/min. Thus, the relative displacement is
$$
540\text{ m/min}\cdot50\text{ min}=27000\text{ m}
$$
Thus, their distance along the track is
$$
\frac{27000\text{ m}}{\pi\,80\text{ m}}=107.429586587\text{ revolutions}
$$
which is the same as
$$
0.429586587\text{ revolutions}=2.69917213\text{ radians}
$$
[image]

The arc length, in green, is $r\theta$. The chord length, in red, is $2r\sin(\theta/2)$. With $r=40\text{ m}$ and $\theta=2.69917213\text{ radians}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#090}{\text{arc length}}&=107.966885\text{ m}\\
\color{#C00}{\text{chord length}}&=78.0506096\text{ m}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Everything makes sense until the last sentence.  The diameter, not the radius, is equal to $80~\text{m}$.

Comment: Thanks. All the other numbers are correct, though.

Answer (score 0):

Every time they pass each other they are 0 meters apart. Circumference of the track is pi x diameter = 251.33. 3000/251.33=11.94 so they should be .06 laps apart. .06x251.33 = 15.08 meters apart on the track (that's circular distance).

Comment: Wouldn't the radius just be half of the diameter, so $r = 40$ meters?

Comment: Sorry. Misread the question. Do you still get the idea? I can redo my calculations if you want.

Comment: I am still not able to understand mainly because I can't visualize it. Can you show me a picture of how this looks like? If not, then hopefully I will be able to understand through your calculations.

Comment: As far as track distance goes, once they are exactly opposite each other then they are getting closer together. So when they are 3/4 of the track away from each other we can also say they are only 1/4 of the track from each other. Think about it in terms of a clock. This is the classic example of modular arithmetic. If I ask you what time it is 25 hours after it is 3:00 you do not need to do all the math because you know 24 hours after 3:00 it's 3:00 again, so 25 hours after 3:00 and 1 hour after 3:00 are the same. Does that help? I updated my calculations for the circular distance btw